# Toggle menu on mobile not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

my toggle menu on mobile is not showing. My website is https://eshop.kerous.cz but when i click the button on top right it doesnt show the menu. Could u please somehow help me to get it fixed. It was working, but then stopped.

My css file on the hosting website is here, If u would need anything else let me know please.

```css
.subcategories li a {
    border-color: #000;
    color: #000;
}
.navigation-in  ul.menu-level-2 a:hover {
  color: black !important;
}
.navigation-in > ul > li > a {
    color: #000 !important;
}
.box-bg-variant .categories a {
    color: #000 !important;
}
.navigation-in {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    line-height: 16px !important;
}
#navigation {
    height: 34px !important;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. First of all, we do not debug external websites. But from the CSS you shared, the only thing that could be related to the problem is the styles for `navigation` . Setting a forced height might be the issue there. Try removing that, see if the problem gets resolved, then find a better different way to achieve what you wanted to achieve by using `height: 34px !important`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your menu doesn't contain height on responsive. That's why the menu is not showing. The below code will help you in showing the menu on mobile devices

```
@media(max-width: 767px) {
    .navigation-in {
        height: auto;
    }

    #navigation {
        height: auto !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put media query for the mobile menu. You need to write the below CSS in your CSS file.

```css
@media (max-width : 767.98px){
#navigation {
    height: auto !important;
}
}
```